# How to read the properties of an object inside an arraylist

Tags: c#, arrays, object, properties, arraylist

I'm having some issues reading the properties of an item I have placed into an arraylist and I can't find the answer anywhere.

```
ArrayList itemsArrayList = new ArrayList();

itemsArrayList.Add(abyssalScepter);         
itemsArrayList.Add(aegisOfTheLegion);

itemInBuildAbilityPower = itemsArrayList[0].abilityPower;
```

I need to be able to read the properties of the objects in the array so I can apply their values elsewhere but this gets me nowhere.

Comment: What do you mean, get's you nowhere? PLease be specific. Do you have a compile error? A runtime error? If so tell us the error/stack trace. Also please tell us what are these objects in the list.

Comment: I would recommend elder_george's answer as it is the correct way to do it although Yahia's answer is very nice for things that are of different type but contain the same property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to cast object to the expected type (and hope it's really of this type).

```
itemInBuildAbilityPower = ((Item)itemsArrayList[0]).abilityPower;
```

The better option (if the infrastructure code is yours) to use generic container, e.g. `List<T>`.

```
List<Item> itemsArrayList = new List<Item>

itemsArrayList.Add(abyssalScepter);         
itemsArrayList.Add(aegisOfTheLegion);

itemInBuildAbilityPower = itemsArrayList[0].abilityPower;
```

Comment: I had to change it to `List<item> itemsArrayList = new List<item>();` but it is working now thank you so much! Now im just having trouble adding them to the list box

Comment: Do you use WinForms or WPF/Silverlight?

Comment: WinForms. I need to basically add the property "itemName" from every object in the array to a listbox

Comment: I was able to fix the problem, turns out I just had the wrong syntax. Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var itemInBuildAbilityPower = itemsArrayList[0].GetType().GetProperty ("abilityPower").GetGetMethod().Invoke (itemsArrayList[0], null);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! however I'm getting the following error: Error 1 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo' does not contain a definition for 'GetMethod' and no extension method 'GetMethod' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\LolBuddy\LolBuddy\LolBuddy\Form1.cs 49 99 LolBuddy

Answer (score 1):

Building on elder_george's answer, here is an example of what you could do if `abyssalScepter` and `aegisOfTheLegion` are not the exact same type:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
class Power { }
interface IAbilityPower { Power abilityPower { get; set; } }
class Scepter : IAbilityPower { public Power abilityPower { get; set; } }
class Aegis : IAbilityPower { public Power abilityPower { get; set; } }


class Test
{
        public static void Main()
        {
                var abyssalScepter = new Scepter();
                var aegisOfTheLegion = new Aegis();
                var itemsList = new List<IAbilityPower>();

                itemsList.Add(abyssalScepter);
                itemsList.Add(aegisOfTheLegion);

                var power = itemsList[0].abilityPower;
        }
}
```